# lazy render children

Tags: reactjs, null, components, lazy-evaluation, children

Take a look at this simple example:

```
 const List = function({ loading, entity }) {
    return (
        <Layout loading={loading}>
            <span>Name: {entity.name}</span>
        </Layout>
    );
};
```

`Layout` component is rendering its `children` only when `loading` is `false`. But the problem here is that `React` is resolving `Layout` children immediatelly. Since `entity` is `null` (while `loading=true`) I get error that it can't read `name` of `null`. Is there a simple way to avoid this error since this `span` will always be rendered when `entity` is not `null`?

Currently I know about 3 options:

1. Move this `span` to `stateless function` which receives `entity` as `prop`
2. Wrap whole `children` of `Layout` in `function` and then support `function children` in `Layout`
3. Just use `{entity && <span>Name: {entity.name}</span>}`

Why do I have to use one of these options and can I make `React` to consider those `children` as function and resolve block inside later on before the render?

Comment: what is the goal? lazy loading? request the chunk file only when the user reach the component? Or request the chunk only if the var loading is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the same problem.

What worked for me was passing children as a function:

```
  ready: boolean;
  children?: () => ReactNode,
}> = ({ ready, children }) => {
  return (
      <div>{
        ready ?
            children() :
            (
                <div>not ready</div>
            )
      }</div>
  );
};


<Layout loading={loading}>
    {() => 
        <span>Name: {entity.name}</span>
    } 
</Layout>
```

Though it's still not perfect.